# Lost styles while dragging elements

Tags: reactjs, react-sortable-hoc

I develop a project in React.js where I use [react-sortable-hoc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sortable-hoc) plugin for drag elements. I want to drag sections with inputs.

Before dragging it looks fine:
[image: before dragging]

If I drag element, it looks like this:
[image]

So styles in input, textarea and all form elements are lost while I dragging it.

Could you help me why styles lost and how I can fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: My guess is that while dragging there is a new element being created which is placed elsewhere in the DOM where the styles aren't applied. Without your markup and css it's impossible to tell.

Comment: I don't think so. If it'd like you wrote, "02" in circle would be corrupted too.

Comment: Regardless, please post your code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you dragging element, react-sortable-hoc plugin appends this element to `body`. If you have cascade in your styles, for example:

```
.parent-component .draggable-element {
 // some styles
}
```

This style will not apply because of in that moment element with `draggable-element` class don't be a child for element with `parent-component` class.

Comment: Nice reply! It fixed my problem. Thank you :)

Comment: It happened that I faced the same problem two days ago :)

Comment: could you help me with one more thing? As I wrote I have some draggable elements with inputs. If I write something to input and drag it to different position, changed input stay in last position. I use DragHandle for this. Thank you for your help.

Comment: It's hard to say, what is the cause of such behavior. One needs to see the code.

Comment: could we write via skype?

Comment: You saved me so much time with this. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. Cascading styles is the last thing I would have thought about. You really saved a lot of my time.